# HttpSessionManager getSessionIds() returns nullpointerException

Tags: spring

I have this code, which is returning a `NullPointerException`. What's the matter?

```
public static void createMultiLogin(HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
{


        HttpSessionManager sessionManager =(HttpSessionManager) httpRequest.getAttribute(HttpSessionManager.class.getName());
        String alias = httpRequest.getParameter("userdetails");
        System.out.println("Inside createMultiLogin "+alias);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        SessionRepository<Session> sessionRepository =(SessionRepository<Session>)httpRequest.getAttribute(SessionRepository.class.getName());


        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sessionManager.getSessionIds(httpRequest).entrySet()) {
                String aliasId = entry.getKey();
                String sessionId = entry.getValue();

                Session storedSession = sessionRepository.getSession(sessionId);
                HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession(false);
                    if(storedSession.getAttribute("ssouserid") != null)
                    {
                            httpSession.setAttribute("ssouserid", storedSession.getAttribute("ssouserid"));
                    }


                System.out.println("printing from the multilogin class "+aliasId +" : "+sessionId);
        }

        if(alias == null || "".equals(alias.trim()))
        {
                alias = sessionManager.getNewSessionAlias(httpRequest);
        }
        httpRequest.setAttribute("alias",alias);
}
```

Stacktrace:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:134)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:954)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Improved formatting. Overall good.

Comment: am getting NullPointerException while trying to get getSessionIds entry set. before calling this method am setting values in session